# Repeat the content in jQuery Slick

Tags: jquery, carousel, slick.js

I have to display dynamically added content using jQuery Slick carousel. Min and Max I have to display 6 content in the slide. If content is less than 6 it should repeat the same content. For example if the `slideToShow:6` but if there is only 4 contents are there. It should repeat the 1st and 2nd content in the last. I can't find out the method in slick for repetition.

```
$('.example').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 6,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: true,
  responsive: [

    {
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Provide us your source code attempted

Comment: Why not just change your slidesToShow dynamically 4 rather than repeat ?

Comment: No actually that is the requirement. it should not resize or show empty space

Comment: You need to check your actual dynamic data length and compare with slidesToShow   length and repeatedly bind 1/2/3rd  data as per needed before append actual Silk div . Silk have no built in function for that.

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop/clone will do the trick:

```html
<ul>
    <li>Slide 1</li>
    <li>Slide 2</li>
    <li>Slide 3</li>
    <li>Slide 4</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        var slidesToShow = 6;
        var slideWrapper = $("ul");
        var slides = $("li");
        var totalSlides = slides.length;

        if (totalSlides > 0 && totalSlides < slidesToShow) {
            // Calculate how many additional elements are required
            var diff = slidesToShow - totalSlides;

            // Start cloning from position [0]
            var slideToClone = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < diff; i++) {
                // Ensure the element about to be cloned exists
                if (slideToClone >= slides.length) {
                    slideToClone = 0;
                }

                // Clone/append slide
                slides.eq(slideToClone).clone().appendTo(slideWrapper);

                // Increment iterator to copy next slide
                slideToClone++;
            }
        }

        // Finally, initialise slick
        // slideWrapper.slick();
    })
</script>
```